# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x} } dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am having trouble with the following integral

> Evaluate
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x} } dx$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x} } dx=\int_0^\infty 3ue^{-u^3}\sin(u^3)du$$
let $u=\sqrt[3]{x}\rightarrow dx=3x^{2/3}du$

How does one proceed from here? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try splitting the sine into complex components and using the gamma function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s use the [definition of the gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and the [complex nature of the sine function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{e^x\sqrt[3] x}dx=\frac{i}{2}\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac13 } e^{-x}\left(e^{-ix}-e^{ix}\right)dx=\frac i2\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac13} e^{-x(1+i)}dx-\frac i2\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac13}e^{x(i-1)}dx=\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{Γ\left(\frac23\right)}{(1-i)^\frac23}-\frac{Γ\left(\frac23\right)}{(1+i)^\frac23}\right)=\frac{3\Gamma\left(\frac53\right)}
{4\sqrt[3]2}= \frac{3\Gamma\left(\frac53\right)}
{2^\frac73}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3\sqrt[3] 2 \Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}= 0.53738206038361965917757281552415611212622673003414… $$

There are many other alternate forms, but this one is simplest. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: What other ways can you evaluate?

Comment: I think this is the shortest possible answer(+1), but you need to mention that which branch have you considered.

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh  If you mean for the roots, then, could I consider all roots; maybe it would be better to say the principal branch? The complex numbers themselves cancel out. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, taking the principal branch would be better, imo.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari what is an “imo”?

Comment: @Tyma I mean "in my opinion".

Answer (score 2):

You may use Laplace transformation which also uses separation of the real and imaginary part:

Let's consider this one:
$$F(s,q)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\, t^{q-1}dt=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-t(s-i)}\sin t\, t^{q-1}dt$$
where $s\geqslant0$ and $q>0$. Where $q ∈ \mathbb Q$?

Which we know:

$$F(s,q)=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{q-1}\frac{dx}{(s-i)^q}=\Im\frac{(s+i)^q}{(s^2+1)^q}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{q-1}dx$$
$$F(s,q)=\frac{\Gamma(q)}{(1+s^2)^{\frac{q}{2}}}\sin\Big(q\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{s}\Big)$$

in particular at $s = 1$ and $q = \frac{2}{3}$

[image]

Comment: The proof for above is given by [Svyatoslav](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/869237/svyatoslav) [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260460/find-the-laplace-transform-of-frac-sint-sqrt3t)