# Find the Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt[3]{t} }$?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

How to find the Laplace transform of $f(t) =$ $\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt[3]{t} }$?

For these types we can integrate the Laplace transform of $f(t) =\frac{\sin(t)}{{t}^{n} }$ w.r.t $u$ from $s$ to $\infty$ where $n ∈ \mathbb Z$, in particular,

$$L\frac{f(t)}{t}=\int_s^\infty F(u)du.$$

But, what if $n ∈ \mathbb Q$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x} } dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260419/evaluate-int-0-infty-frace-x-sinx-sqrt3x-dx)

Comment: This same question was posted thrice from yesterday. First one was answered by me. Then again one was posted and then this. But since it answered your query it's fine. My bad .  1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260419/evaluate-int-0-infty-frace-x-sinx-sqrt3x-dx    and 2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259863/int-0-infty-frace-x-cosx-2-sinx-2x1-3dx/4259887#4259887 . These are the same question

Comment: I have edited my comment and linked them

Comment: No no it's not your fault. But you see when you type the question. You will see similar posts . So a good idea would be to just go through the posts which look similar . If they answer your question then fine. If they don't you are more than welcome to post your question.

Comment: @Darshan Patil, I know it's not what you asked for, however I think it's good to point out that for integrals with fractional powers such as this one, Mellin Transforms (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) may be more suitable than Laplace Transforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote
$$I(s,q)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\, t^{q-1}dt=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-t(s-i)}\sin t\, t^{q-1}dt$$
where $s\geqslant0$ and $q>0$.

We can evaluate the integral via integration in the complex plane, making the substitution $x=t(s-i)$. Making this substitution we also change the integration path, but it can be shown that the additional integral (along the segment of the big circle of radius R) tends to zero as $R\to\infty$.

Therefore,
$$I(s,q)=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{q-1}\frac{dx}{(s-i)^q}=\Im\frac{(s+i)^q}{(s^2+1)^q}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{q-1}dx$$
$$I(s,q)=\frac{\Gamma(q)}{(1+s^2)^{\frac{q}{2}}}\sin\Big(q\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{s}\Big)$$
In the particular case of $q=\frac{2}{3}$ and $s=1$
$$I\Big(1;\frac{2}{3}\Big)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}\sin t}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}dt=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{4}{3}}}\Gamma\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)$$

Comment: Hi Svyatsoslav! I have seen a few of your best solutions using contour integrals I think you are the right person who can help me know a good source of textbooks dealing with complex integrals.

Comment: @Darshan P. Among the modern books in English I would recommend MATHEMATICAL METHODS FOR PHYSICISTS - A Comprehensive Guide (SEVENTH EDITION) by George B. Arfken and other. Chapter 11 - Complex Variable Theory. There are a lot of interesting staff in this book (besides complex integration), and a lot of interesting problems to practise. More difficult for studying is the work of Iaroslav V. Blagouchine “Rediscovery of Malmsten's integrals, their evaluation by contour integration methods and some related results” (it is easy to find this work in the internet). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!